# representation of conformal group in d>2

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, definition

In P. Di Francesco, P. Mathieu, D. Snchal they fix the generators of the conformal group acting on a scalar field by somewhat arbitrarily defining 
$$\Phi'(x)=\Phi(x)-i\omega_a G_a\Phi(x)$$ 
and by arbitrary I mean the sign. The "full" transformation would then be given by the exponentiation
$$\Phi'(x)=e^{-i\omega_a G_a}\Phi(x)$$
the generators are given in eq. 4.18 and the commutation relations are in eq. 4.19. But by looking at the action of the group in the coordinates, I think we could get the same representation 4.18 by requiring
$$x'^\mu=e^{ i\omega_aT_a}x^\mu=\alpha^\mu+\omega^\mu_{~~\nu} x^\nu + \lambda x^\mu +2(\beta \cdot x)x^\mu-\beta^\mu x^2$$
but the problem is that, in order to reproduce 4.18 the sign of the exponential is not the same as the one for $G_a$. I would have expected that the field transform in a similar way:
$$\Phi'(x)=e^{i\omega_a G_a} \Phi(x)$$
 In fact it seems that there is not a "standard" definition. For example in this [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491669902784) by Mack and Salam, as well as in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0792341589) by Fradkin and Palchik, the generators as well as the commutation relations disagree among each other.

Anyway I would like to know how the generators should be defined so that everything is consistent from the Lie theory/representation theory point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a conformal theory of fields $\Phi$ defined on Minkowski spacetime $M=\mathbb R^{3,1}$ and with target space $V$.  Let $\rho_M$ denote a representation of the conformal group $G$ on $M$ and let $\rho_V$ denote a representation of $G$ on $V$.  Then we can define an action $\rho_F$ of $G$ on fields $\Phi$ as follows:
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(\rho_M(g)x) = \rho_V(g)\Phi(x)
$$
This is a more notationally descriptive version of di-Francesco eq. 2.114;
$$
  \Phi'(x') = \mathcal F(\Phi(x))
$$
In other words, the action of $G$ on fields has two parts, a spacetime part, and a target space (aka internal) part.  Now, suppose that we find that there is another representation $\rho_D$ of $G$ acting on fields (by way of differential operators for example) for which
$$
  \Phi(\rho_M(g)x) = \rho_D(g)\Phi(x)
$$
Then notice that the first equation above can be written as follows:
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x) = \rho_D(g^{-1})\rho_V(g)\Phi(x)
$$
How does this manifest itself in terms of signs and generators?  Well, suppose that for any group representation $\rho$ of $G$, we have a corresponding, linear representation $R$ of its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ such that if we write an element $g\in G$ as the exponential of a Lie algebra element $X$; $g = e^X$, then
$$
  \rho(g) = e^{R(X)}
$$
Then we can write the transformation of the fields as
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x) = e^{-R_D(X)}e^{R_V(X)}\Phi(x)
$$
For any $X\in\mathfrak g$.  If these Lie algebra representations commute (as they would if, for example, $R_D$ is a representation via differential operators and $R_V$ is some spacetime-independent representation on the target space), then we can write
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x) = e^{R_V(X)-R_D(X)}\Phi(x)
$$
Now, suppose that we choose a basis $X_a$ for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ such that every element $X\in \mathfrak g$ can be written as
$$
  X = i\omega_aX_a
$$
for some real numbers $\omega_a$.  Then using linearity of the representations $R_D, R_V$ we have
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x) = e^{-i\omega_a(R_D(X_a) - R_V(X_a))}\Phi(x)
$$
So if we use di-Francesco's notation
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x) = e^{-i\omega_aG_a}\Phi(x)
$$
then we have
$$
  G_a = R_D(X_a) - R_V(X_a)
$$
To see that this leads to consistent signs etc., let's look at an example:

**Example.** Translations

Consider a field whose target space transforms trivially under translations;
$$
  (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x+a) = \Phi(x)
$$
Then if $ia^\mu P_\mu$ is the Lie algebra element that corresponds to translations $x\to x+a$, and if we define
$$
  R_V(P_\mu) = 0, \qquad R_D(P_\mu) = -i\partial_\mu
$$
Then we have
$$
  G_\mu = -i\partial_\mu
$$
so that
$$
  e^{-ia^\mu G_\mu}\Phi(x) = e^{-a^\mu\partial_\mu}\Phi(x) = \Phi(x-a) = (\rho_F(g)\Phi)(x)
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now there's still something that is bugging me. In your first eq. you write the field on the LHS with a prime. In Mack and Salam paper they use a similar relation to see that  $\rho_V(g,x=0)$ is a rep. of the stability subgroup of $x=0$. Then I guess that in order to be completely consistent with the notation we can replace $\Phi'$ by $(R(g)\Phi)$ right?

Comment: @Barefeg Sure thing.  I changed the notation a bit in line with your observation.  Basically, you're right, if I want to be more descriptive, then I note that I can write $\Phi'$ as some group action $\rho_F$ of $G$ on the fields; $\Phi' = \rho_F(g)\Phi$.